# Item Selection Event for NSTableView not triggered

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, storyboard

I have a scrollview containing a table column.
[image]

I need to display list of added files.This is achieved as follows

```
@IBOutlet weak var tview: NSTableView!
```

---

```
self.tview.delegate = self as? NSTableViewDelegate
self.tview.dataSource = self
```

---

```
extension ViewController:NSTableViewDataSource{
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return fileArray.count
    }

        func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
            return fileArray[row].path
        }
    }
```

---

How can i hook to the event when user clicks on a filename? I have tried adding

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
    {

    }
```

In the extention method... but the breakpoint is not triggered when selection changes.

Comment: Does the table view delegate adopt the `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol?

Comment: @Willeke Adding `NSTableViewDelegate` solved the issue.Is it necessary to define the extension method? How does `objectValueFor` work even when protocol is not defined.

Comment: @Willeke There is no parameter to identify the selected row in the `tableViewSelectionDidChange` method

Comment: @Willeke Solved the issue... but there is another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61265451/unable-to-set-image-of-nsimageview-using-file-path

Comment: `tableView(_:objectValueFor:row:)` is a method of the `NSTableViewDataSource` protoco.