# Unable to set Image of NSImageView using file path

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, storyboard, nsimage

I have hooked to Selection changed event of NSTableView.I need to display the selected image in the imageview

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification)
       {
        let table = notification.object as! NSTableView

        print(fileArray[table.selectedRow].path);
        img_view.image=NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: fileArray[table.selectedRow].path))
       }
```

The console prints

```
/Users/myname/Downloads/435_v9_bc.jpg
```

But the imageview does not display the image.

Update 1:

```
 print(fileArray[table.selectedRow].path);
 img_view.image=NSImage(byReferencing: URL(string: fileArray[table.selectedRow].path)!)
```

***Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***

Console still prints

```
/Users/myname/Downloads/123_1 (1).jpeg
```

Comment: NSImage(byReferencingFile: "/Users/myname/Downloads/435_v9_bc.jpg")

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha Please see the udpate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URL(string:` is the wrong API, for file system paths you have to use `URL(fileURLWithPath`.

```
img_view.image = NSImage(byReferencing: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileArray[table.selectedRow].path))
```

---

However `fileArray[table.selectedRow]` seems to be already an URL so there is a still easier way

```
img_view.image = NSImage(contentsOf: fileArray[table.selectedRow])
```